# How does a date compare with a datetime object in R?

Tags: r, date, datetime

How does a date compare with a datetime object in R ?

Is the time portion set to 00:00:00 for a date object when comparing with a time stamp?

I did this experiment to find out:

```
> Sys.Date()
[1] "2024-02-06"
>  Sys.time() 
[1] "2024-02-06 13:35:40 IST"
>  Sys.time() > Sys.Date()
[1] TRUE
Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("Ops.POSIXt", "Ops.Date") for ">" 
>
```

The above throws a warning but it seems to me that for any Sys.Date() the corresponding Sys.time() will be greater or equal to it if the "timestamp" automatically attached with Sys.Date() is 00:00:00.

Do I understand correctly?

Comment: The duplicate link has a slightly different use case, but the error message/underlying cause is completely identical to yours.